# Open Source XSS Prevention Script

Tags: open-source, xss

I am looking for damn good open source XSS prevention script to implement in my php mvc framework.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not quite what you are asking for, but check out: http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/

Answer (score 2):

You might check out the AntiSamy project, managed by the Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP).

It's named AntiSamy after Samy Kamkar, creator of the MySpace worm.

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

Answer (score 0):

Although [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998274.aspx) is not for PHP it could at least give you some ideas for writing your own code. I suppose PHP has the same built in functions to validate/parse URL, encode HTML, etc ...
See if that helps you at all ....